# access truncate method in model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`truncate` is intended as a view helper.  However, if a model method needs to be invoked to create a string for use by a controller (with end intent of carting off the string to a dynamically generated javascript)

```
 "#{title}" + " " + "#{main_text.truncate(length: 120)}"
```

fails with `undefined method 'truncate' for nil:NilClass`
The error is misleading as `"#{title}" + " " + "#{main_text}"` renders properly.

How can one effect truncate then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`main_text` is `nil` that's why you are getting the error

```
undefined method 'truncate' for nil:NilClass
```

To make sure you handle the `nil` you can use safe navigation operator

```
"#{title} #{main_text&.truncate(120)}"
```

This will work on ruby 2.3+

If you are using ruby < 2.3 you can make use of

```
"#{title} #{main_text.try(:truncate, 120)}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are passing in `nil` to the `truncate` helper the view should still render...i.e. this should not throw an error..

```
<%= truncate(nil, length: 120) %>
```

So, try `<%= truncate(main_text, length: 120) %>`

It looks like you are trying to use Ruby truncate instead of the Rails view helper...which is why it's throwing `undefined method 'truncate' for nil:NilClass`.
But...`main_text` is still nil, which you will need to figure out if this is a problem.

As far as `"#{title}" + " " + "#{main_text}"` rendering properly...it's most likely not. Similar to the above, you can say

```
"#{nil}" + " " + "#{nil}"
```

And it will still render the blank space without error.